# Port binding error when connecting to localhost Kafka broker from localhost Consumer in Docker container

Tags: docker, networking, apache-kafka

I have a Zookeeper running on port 2181 (default) and a Kafka server listening on port 9090 on my local machine.

When I run kafka CLI locally, or consumer/producer apps locally, I have no problem connecting.

I then try to bundle a Kafka consumer into a Docker container, and run that Docker container locally, e.g.:

`docker run -p 9092:9092 --rm <DOCKER_IMAGE>`

This gives the error:

`(Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:9090 failed: port is already allocated.)`

This makes sense since Kafka Server is bound to 9092, as shown in `nmap -p 9092 localhost`:

`PORT     STATE SERVICE
9092/tcp open  XmlIpcRegSvc`

I'd have no problem mapping the Docker container to a different port via `-p XXX:9090`, but how do I get the local Kafka server to listen on that new port without binding to it?

Answer (score 1):

So after some digging I found a few options. *(Note: I'm on a mac so #2 may not be applicable to everyone).*

1. Include `--network=host` in the `docker run` command (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)).
2. Don't change the `docker run` command at all, and instead connect to broker at `host.docker.internal:9092` inside the container consumer/publisher code. As seen [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#i-cannot-ping-my-containers).

I wasn't able to get #1 to work out for me (I'm sure it's user error). However #2 worked perfectly and just required a config change inside the container.

Comment: Also if you run Kafka in Docker,  might want to see  https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/